# infinitely generating game object in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, duplicates, infinite, gameobject

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class instantiatescript : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject house;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
     house = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("house");
    CreatePrefab ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {


}


void CreatePrefab()
{



    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        Instantiate(house, new Vector3(i * 0f, 0f, 2.0f), Quaternion.identity);


}
}
```

i need to generate the game object house infinitely along the z direction.but now this code actually does nothing ,can any one provide a reference for the infinite generation of object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is somewhat right, but:

- `house` doesn't need to be initialized with an instantiated `GameObject`. Just leave the declaration as is and assign a prefab through the Inspector at the variable;
- That `for` cycle should consider multiple `x` values and generate a house at each iteration. But what are you expecting by multipling an arbitrary `i` by 0? The coordinates will remain always the same. Maybe you want to add?

Comment: yaa i need to add new cloned object so it looks like a lot of houses in the game...actually i am doing a runner game like temple run

Comment: OK, understood. So, as a first try, follow the second point (that is, substituting "*" with "+".

Comment: I would say you should couple the generation to the player movement. You don't want to generate 1000 gameobjects ahead of time. Instead, you want to generate (and destroy or move) them a little bit to the right (and left) of the screen. E.g. you could do this according to the running speed of the player.

Comment: @GunnarB. why my code is not working,can you provide some refference

Comment: @GunnarB. I agree with you, on the long-term implementation. In fact, I've just answered to address the immediate problem.
at Martinj: I have already give you an advice. Have you tried that? I think it's pretty straightforward...You could at least tell me if it works or not, before asking again at someone else with "code is not working".

Comment: @Andrea  Instantiate(**house**, new Vector3(i * 0f, 0f, 2.0f), Quaternion.identity); //am not getting that prefab house over the